# What is the best practice to implement site search in Static ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, search

Suppose We have a static website built in **ASP.NET**. What is the best way to implement site search in this scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to store all of your page content in a database or storage mechanism.

If you are using SQL Server 2005+ products, they provide full text indexing facilities allow you to quickly and easily search for a specific phrase or keyword.

In addition to this, the results are 'ranked' as to how useful the database thinks the match will be to you.

Here is a description of the [ranking system in SQL Server 2005](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and how to implement it

Alternatively, use a pre-built product like [Google Search](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUB04YCUQ7k)

Answer (score 0):

Alternative I like to suggest some search components from companies that have done great job, (that I have test and see).

http://www.karamasoft.com/UltimateSearch/Features.aspx

http://www.sitesearchasp.net/default.aspx